# How to add optional route in vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a button like this:

```
<router-link :to="{path: '/foo/bar', params: {id: 1}">
```

and my route for the above is defined in `route.js` file as:

```
...
{
 path: 'foo/bar',
 component: fooComponent()
}
...
```

Now, my question is how do I make my route accept a conditional url prop like `/foo/bar/1` and `/foo/bar` because now, it only accepts `/foo/bar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make it as optional parameter, use question mark `?`.

```
'foo/bar/:id?'
```

Comment: yes optional. It should show the same page if/not :id exists

Comment: Yep, it will open the same page.

Answer (score 1):

```
path: 'foo/bar/:id'
```

Here you can read about it: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html

Comment: but that would expect an id always

Comment: I think that will help you: path: `'foo/bar/:id?'` // 


https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp#parameters
Parameters > Parameter Modifiers > Optional